# Not able to insert Grid view text box value to Mysql Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

**My Second Error**

[image: My Second Errord]I am trying to insert textbox value that are present in the gridview to data base but in the cs page that gives me some error am not sure where i am going wrong.

[image]

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Names">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStudent_Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentFirstName") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Register Number">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtreg_number" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentRegID") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Marks">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txttotal_marks" runat="server" Text='' ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Marks Scored">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtmarks_scored" runat="server" Text='' ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

CS code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.Visible = true;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox txtUsrId = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtStudent_Name");
                string UserID = txtUsrId.Text;
                string query = "insert into details (name) values('" + UserID + "')";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, constr);
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass your `MySqlConnection` instead of your connection string as a second parameter in your `MySqlCommand` constructor. Error message clearly says, there is no overload as `new MySqlCommand(string, string)` but there *is* an overload as `new MySqlCommand(string, MySqlConnection)`.

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

And use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically.

By the way, since you try to `INSERT` to your database, you just need to call [`ExecuteNonQuery` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.executenonquery.aspx) instead of using `MySqlDataAdapter`. Since you try to insert, there is no data to fill your `DataTable`. I suggest to re-think your design.

I usually use these syntax for that by the way;

```
using(var con = new MySqlConnection(conStr))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into details (`name`) values(@id)";
    con.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
         cmd.Parameters.Clear();
         TextBox txtUsrId = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtStudent_Name");    
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsrId.Text;
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

And `NAME` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in MySQL. Depending on your database provider is case sensitive or not, you *might* need to change it to *non-reserved* word.

Comment: i tried ur code am not sure how to do that can u please help me out with full example

Comment: @Shaik I put an example. But consider to changing your logic. You try to insert your database but you try to fill your `DataTable` with something. This does not make sense, right? You _can_ fill it with some `SELECT` statement for example. I assumed your `name` column is `VarChar` typed in my example.

Comment: I am sorry, and thaks for ur support and one more thing is that `cmd.CommanText` gives me an error i have uploaded an image but iam really thank full to ur support